# Why is my input repeating multiple times?

Tags: python

I am currently making a project just for the sake of bettering my skills, but I have ran into a very confusing problem. When I run the first section, Encode, it all works properly and how I would like it to. But when I run the second section, Decode, it asks for a number between one and 12, and the message twice. Can anyone help me understand why this is occurring?

```
import sys
import string
k = input('Enter keycode: ')
if k == '220997332':
    print('|E1-D12| |E2-D11||E3-D10| |E4-D9| |E5-D8| |E6-D7| |E7-D6| |E8-D5| |E9-D4| |E10-D3| |E11-D2| |E12-D1|')
    y = input('D for Decode |OR| E for Encode: ')
    if y == 'E' or 'e':
        x = input('Enter you message: ')
        z = input('Enter any number between 1-12: ')
        if z == '1':
            str1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZnopqrstuvwxyz,.?!:;"
            str1key ="QETUO{|ADGJL'ZCBM>WRIYP}SFHK:XVN!@#$%^&*()_+-=~`;][1490563"
            q = x.maketrans(str1, str1key)
            print(x.translate(q))
            sys.exit() 
    if y == 'D' or 'd':
        X = input('Enter you message: ')
        Z = input('Enter any number between 1-12: ')
        if Z == '12':
            str12 ="QETUO{|ADGJL'ZCBM>WRIYP}SFHK:XVN!@#$%^&*()_+-=~`;][1490563"
            str12key = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZnopqrstuvwxyz,.?!:;"
            Q = X.maketrans(str12, str12key)
            print(x.translate(Q))
            sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the If condition. No matter what the user enters e or d or anything both the if blocks will be executed because the condition says that either (y=='E') should be true or ('e') should be true. and bool('e') is always true. The same happens with the next if block which is if (y=='D') or ('d').

To fix this you just need to correct the condition as `if y=='E' or y=='e'` and the same for the decoding.

For clearing your doubt, why it doesn't print message twice in encoding is because on the successful execution of encoding it runs `sys.exit()` which stops the program execution and skips rest of the code.

Hope this helps!!